# Entity Framework Core DbContext.SaveChanges throws System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type System.Boolean to type System.Int16

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, entity-framework-core

I am using .net core 2.2 with entity framework using MySql.Data.EntityFramework.Core. Bump into this exception when I do the following:

```
DbContext.MyDbSet.Add(new MyClass());
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   System.Boolean to type System.Int16

I have added the following code snippet into OnModelCreating function:

```
            foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
                foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
                    if (property.ClrType == typeof(bool) || property.ClrType == typeof(Boolean))
                        property.SetValueConverter(new BoolToZeroOneConverter<Int16>());
```

What do I miss?

Comment: I think your model and database type mismatch.

Comment: Agreed, it would make sense to ensure your C# model and your database fields have the same types. Change whichever one is appropriate. Then you'll have no issues.

Comment: I think its the MySql package Look into this https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/866

Comment: @AhmetArslan - You should have added your comment as an answer - its the correct answer for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to database schema and model mismatch and I added the following to fix the issue:

```
                    else if (property.ClrType == typeof(Nullable<bool>) || property.ClrType == typeof(Nullable<Boolean>))
                        property.SetValueConverter(new BoolToZeroOneConverter<Nullable<Int16>>());
```

Answer (score 4):

try belove code:

```
[Required]
[Column(TypeName = "BIT")]
public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the MySQL EF.Core implementation: [bug 93028](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93028).

On [other](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/866#issuecomment-475600116) [sites](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14051#issuecomment-443869722), people have reported fixing the issue by switching to [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql).

Answer (score -1):

This is typcally caused by mismatch between entity class property type and database column type.